# $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(... You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: database

I am making a database request in wordpress to make this question:
select * from tc_chat_clt;

How ever a error appears, what am I doing wrong?

```
$users = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM %s',`tc_chat_clt`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP views backticks (ie, ``) as delimiting something that should be executed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php), not as a quotation character. Use single quotes (`'`) instead.

```
$users = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM %s', 'tc_chat_clt'));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, like I had posted the error appears like this:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '''' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM ''

Comment: and if I use this cotes ' , firstly I was using them the error says this : [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''tc_chat_clt'' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM 'tc_chat_clt'

Comment: if I use $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM tc_chat_clt');  the code goes well; but I think it is better to use prepare();

Comment: `->prepare()` isn't strictly necessary in this *specific* case, because you're not passing it any variables. But using `->prepare()` is a good habit to cultivate.